# Strange behaviour in Angular UI-Router onEnter callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having a strange problem with the onEnter callback for a UI-Router state. What I originally wanted to do was to change the variable `data.pagetitle` in the onEnter callback.

I've created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/r2efUV1su0wQK6Blfk9a?p=preview) to demonstrate the problem. I put a `console.log` on line 13 and 14 of script.js. It seems as if the $state variable differs between these two lines.

So two questions:

1. Why does $state seem to be different on line 13 and 14
2. How do I edit a 'data' object in the onEnter callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add your custom variables inside the *params* parameter of the *state* and then you could simply access them in the controller.

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ui.router']);

// Routes configuration
var Config = function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            template : '{{ pageTitle }}',
            controller : 'MainCtrl',
            params : { pageTitle : 'Hello, world!' }
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('main');

};

Config.$inject = [
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider'
];

app.config(Config);

// Controller 
var MainCtrl = function($scope, $state){

    // Methods
    function initCtrl(){
        $scope.pageTitle = $state.params.pageTitle;
    }

    // Init controller
    initCtrl();

};

MainCtrl.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    '$state'
];

app.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
```